# sbt run fails with "Protocol error" for sub-project

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to run a sbt/scala project, and I am getting this cryptic error.

```
sbt @ PROJECT_NAME > SUBMODULE_NAME/compile
[info] Compiling 24 Scala sources to /usr/src/PROJECT_NAME/SUBMODULE_NAME/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] Protocol error
[error] one error found
[error] (SUBMODULE_NAME/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 29 s, completed 08-Mar-2016 10:30:20
```

Happens with a few of our internal projects, but only for ones with subprojects. There are no other messages that seem related, and google has been unhelpful. Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas how I might get more verbose output, at this point I am resorting to trying to find the string "protocol error" in the sources of dependencies

Comment: You can add [`logLevel := Level.Debug`](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch18s14.html) in your sbt file.

Comment: hmm, that adds more output, but nothing relevant to the error :(

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't much to offer, but have you looked at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/oBvT6352--Y), they seem to suggest a couple of options, one of them being "clean all delete target file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was to do with VirtualBox shared folders, and naming issue. Moving where my shared folder is mounted solves the issue.

Related:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15497
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15868